How do I "Group by" with timestamps in a Grafana's table?
Currently I have a table in a grafana's panel and I want to transform timestamps in date with this format "YYYY-MM-DD". Then I want to "Group by" all of my data with the "new date".
I already tried the override's option but it doesn't work.
This is a screenshot of my situation

If it's possible it's better to use datasource capabilities for this purpose. What is your datasource?

I agree with ebabeshko here. But if it's not possible, you can try transformations. I think Format time and Group by should be close to what is needed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have put up a screenshot, I hope it helps you understand better ?
